# Templated overloaded operator resolution, no implicit cast

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have the following code, with a set of templated classes and the operator+ overloaded:

```
template <typename T>
class A { };

template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
    B(const A<T>& a) { }
};

template <typename T>
void operator+(B<T> lhs, B<T> rhs) { /* ... */ }

int main(/* ... */)
{
    A<int> a1, a2;

    a1 + a2;

    return 0;
}
```

Clang ignores the `operator+(...)` as a candidate, because it says it can't match `B` against `A`. As far as I know, the compiler is allowed to do one implicit cast to do overload resolution, but for some reason this isn't happening. Can someone explain me why?

If I remove all templates, the code compiles fine.

Comment: Actually, without the templates, you're not doing an implicit cast but calling `B`'s constructor with an instance of `A` (Edit: this isn't possible with templates because you can't infer `T`).

Comment: The compiler cannot deduce `T` when `B` could have one or more specializations elsewhere with different behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't the ctor used for the implicit casts? That's why the keyword explicit exists, to prevent that. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, C++ attempts to not make the compiler reverse possibly turing-complete processes.

```
template<size_t I> struct index {};

template<class T> struct A {};

template<class T> struct B {};

template<size_t I> struct B< index<I> > {
  B( A< index+1 > ) {};
};

template<class T>
void operator+( B<T>, B<T> ) {}

int main() {
  A< index<3> > one, two;
  one+two;
}
```

as far as the compiler is concerned, `operator+` is no different than the one you wrote.  It needs to find a `B<T>` from `A<index<3>>` to convert the `A` from.

Now, I know and you know that the answer for `T` is `index<2>`, much like in your case the answer for `T` was `int`, but *in the general case* the mapping required might be non-injective (hence not uniquely invertible), or Turing complete (hence requiring solving the halting problem to invert).

So, to prevent compilers from having to (in the general case) solve impossible problems, the compiler does pattern matching on the types of the arguments and on the base types of the arguments when doing template function type deduction.  And nothing else.

We can add a type mapping:

```
template<class T>
struct get_B_type {};
template<class T>
struct get_B_type<A<T>> {
  using type=B<T>;
};
template<class T>
using get_B_type_t = typename get_B_type<T>::type;

template <class T, class U,
  void_t<get_B_type_t<T>>* = nullptr,
  void_t<get_B_type_t<U>>* = nullptr
>
void operator+(T lhs, U rhs) {
  return (get_B_type_t<T>)(lhs) + (get_B_type_t<U>)(rhs);
}
```

where the mapping is explicitly done by us.

Comment: Marked as the answer, because it explains why my example did not work, and provided a workaround using type traits. As a side note: `std::void_t` is only available from C++17 on, but easily definable manually.

Comment: @stjin and can be omitted fom the above in any case, so long as the trait does not return a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit conversions are not considered when performing template argument deduction. The compiler cannot deduce the `T` in a `B<T>` from an `A<U>` even with the constructor you provided. Think about it: how can we convert an `A<int>` to a `B<T>` if we don't know what `T` is?

If the template argument wasn't deduced but was known then the implicit conversion sequences can occur through the converting-constructor. This can be done through explicitly providing the template argument (`operator+<int>(a1,a2)`) which isn't the best solution. Another solution could work by having `A` be a derived class of `B`.

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
};

template <typename T>
class A : public B<T> { };
```

Now since `A<T>` *is-a* `B<T>` the standard derived-to-base conversion can occur and `T` can be deduced by the type of the argument.